# map a custom JavaScript model to a Knockout model with observables

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I receive a model from the server, and it is a (navigation)menu.
So it has 1 root item, with an array of menuitems. The root item also has a title.
the array of menuitems is an array of items with a title and an array of linkItems (objects with properties like controller, action, css etc.)

I have the same model in my knockout viewmodel, but then all the arrays and properties are observable arrays/strings/ints.

Now when I do this

`vm.menuitems(menuitemsfromserver)` I have a menu with an observable array, but all the items 'below' or 'lower' in the tree are 'normal' objects and not observables anymore.

I have seen the `map` method, but I can't make any sense of it.
The models are identical, the only difference is that one consists of observable(-arrays) and the other of plain javascript objects.

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin made especially for that case: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html

From its documentation:

```
// Every time data is received from the server:
ko.mapping.fromJS(data, viewModel);
```

> All properties of an object are converted into an observable. If an update would change the value, it will update the observable.
>
> Arrays are converted into observable arrays. If an update would change the number of items, it will perform the appropriate add/remove actions. It will also try to keep the order the same as the original JavaScript array.

In your case the code would look like:

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(menuitemsfromserver, vm.menuitems)
```

and it would iterate over all properties and all arrays of *menuitemsfromserver* and turn them into observables.

Plugin is not maintained actively lately, as seen here: https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout.mapping, but still, for that purpose, its a useful code.

Comment: Thanks. Will try it.

Comment: Ok, this works, partly. What happens is that it overwrites the original object, so all computed properties are overwritten. One way to solve that which I saw other people do, is first read the entire datamodel and then, after that, add all the computed properties to the viewmodel. That doesn't strike me as a clean way of doing things.

Comment: I'm not sure if I see the whole picture here. The way I usually use the mapping is to map raw server data to observable models, all computed variables are not a part of models but they belong directly to viewmodel. Maybe I can provide some clarifications if more code samples are included in the question?